# How to retrieve all the selected markers on the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm drawing circles on my map and everytime I click on it, I change it's style to let the user know it's selected, it also opens a modal with some information.

What I need to do is undo that style on the circle when I Close this modal.

```
semiCircle[obj].addListener('click', function (event) { 
    if (systems[this.objId].circle.strokeWeight == 2) {
                        systems[this.obj].circle.setOptions({strokeWeight: 4, strokeColor: fullColorPlus(systems[this.objID].circle.strokeColor, 22, 66, 22)});
                        systems[this.objId].circle.selected = true;
                  } 
                  myFunction(this, event)....

});  


function myFunction(elem, event) {
   /* Some code*/  
   openModal();

}
```

When I click on the modal's button to close it.

```
function closeModal() {
  /* Closes the Modal*/

}
```

Is there a way to retrieve the markers I just changed style and marked as selected ? Retrieve selected markers or something like that...

Comment: Code provided, clear objective. Please, provide a reason for the close vote. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.